# Is IHostedService.StopAsync() called when IIS recycles?

Tags: iis, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.2, asp.net-core-hosted-services

This question is with regard to ASP.NET Core 2.2 applications running on IIS, specifically when registering instances of [IHostedService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostedservice?view=aspnetcore-2.2) with the DI container.

Every article I read about [IHostedService.StopAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostedservice.stopasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2) just talks about `StopAsync()` being called when the host "shuts down", but I want to know what happens when IIS recycles.

My question(s):

**1. Is `StopAsync()` called when the IIS recycles?**

**2. Is the answer the same regardless of using `InProcess` hosting or `OutOfProcess` hosting?** (ASP.NET Core supports `InProcess` as of version 2.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is `StopAsync()` called when the IIS recycles?

**Yes**

Reference [Implement background tasks in microservices with IHostedService and the BackgroundService class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice#deployment-considerations-and-takeaways)

> ### Deployment considerations and takeaways
>
> It is important to note that the way you deploy your ASP.NET Core
>   WebHost or .NET Core Host might impact the final solution. For
>   instance, **if you deploy your WebHost on IIS or a regular Azure App
>   Service, your host can be shut down because of app pool recycles.**
>
> .....

*note: **emphasis mine***

which by extension would stop any `IHostedService`,